# How to run Progress bar before calling jsp method

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp. I need to run a java script in body on load. Here in my jsp i have to do a lot of process by calling a method in a bean. The problem is, my script is running after completing the java process. But, i need run this process before calling this method. How can i do this?

tested :

```
  window.load
  window.onpaint
  onload <body>
  ready iquery
  etc
```

Comment: are you getting or posting any variables to jsp?

Comment: Just suggestion, not answer, because I am also not sure. I think you are looking for `onload` event. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp. Load simple page displaying progressBar, then with AJAX, load new things for browser, while same time updating progressBar. When load completes, display what you have loaded, and remove progressBar.

Answer (score 0):

JSP files get loaded entirely inside server before reaching a client's browser. So using an `onload` event in that file is useless.

But there is one way where you could achieve it. You could trick your client.

**Previous page**:

```html
<a href="loader.htm">Click Here to load JSP</a>
```

**Intermediate Loader page**:

```html
<body onload="redirect()">
<!-- use your headers/menu-bar and everything which you need to style -->
<center>
    <img src="path_to_loader_image.gif" />
</center>
<!-- close all the div tags and use your footer section if necessary -->
</body>

<script language=javascript>
function redirect(){
  window.location = "destination.jsp";
}
</script>
```

**Destination JSP page**:

```html
<!-- jsp code -->
```

The above trick can be used only if the link to jsp is done by using `<a>` anchor tag.

Comment: Previous page:

<a href="/XXX.do?method=MMM">Click Here to load JSP</a>